# How to query Sitecore SOLR using special characters?

Tags: sitecore, solr4, sitecore7.5

I want to be able to build a site search page and allow users to include special Solr characters in their query (using Sitecore 7.5 and SOLR 4.7).  For example I would like for users to be able to search for "f(x)".  I have some code that seems to work sometimes.  Basically it escapes the special characters.  If I search for "f(x)" it works fine.  However if I want to have 2 terms in my query and search for "f(x) green" it doesn't work.  It seems to just search for the EXACT phrase "f(x) green".  Regular queries work fine.  If I search for "green yellow" it returns all documents with either green or yellow in them and if I search for "yellow green" I get the same results which is fine.  If I search for "f(x)" I get the results I would expect.  But if I search for "f(x) green" I get no results which is not what I would expect.  My search code is below.

```
var specialSOLRChars = @"\+\-\&\|\!\(\)\{\}\[\]\^\""\~\*\?\:\\";

using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext()) {

   var query = context.GetQueryable<GeneralSearchResultItem>().Where(x => !x.IsStandardValue && x.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);
   var isSpecialMatch = Regex.IsMatch(searchTerm, "[" + specialSOLRChars + "]");
   if (isSpecialMatch) {
      var wildcardText = string.Format("\"*{0}*\"", Regex.Replace(searchTerm, "([" + specialSOLRChars + "])", @"\$1"));
      query = query.Where(i => (i.Content.MatchWildcard(wildcardText) || i.Name.MatchWildcard(wildcardText));
   } 
   else {
      query = query.Where(i => (i.Content.Contains(searchTerm) ||    i.Name.Contains(searchTerm));
   }
   var results = query.GetResults();
   return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you intend to get search results that contain both **f(x)** and **green**, and also containing either of them.

To imitate this behavior you should split the search term using the whitespace and check **Content.Contains()** for both of them separated by an **||** condition. This will give you results when you search for **f(x) green**.